# Trying to echo a single row with multiple columns from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm at the end of the user process, and I can't seem to echo all of the data in a single row with 10 columns. Here's my code:

```
$state = $_POST['state'];

$city = $_POST['city'];

$jobTitle = $_POST['jobTitle'];



try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TeacherData;port=8889","censored","censored");
}   catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Could not connect to database.";
exit;
}




$sql = "SELECT
TOT_EMP, 
H_MEAN, 
JOBS_1000,
A_MEAN,
H_PCT10,
H_MEDIAN,
H_PCT90,
A_PCT10,
A_MEDIAN,
A_PCT90
FROM teacherdataall 
WHERE PRIM_STATE='" . $state . "' 
AND AREA_NAME='" . $city . "' 
AND OCC_TITLE='" . $jobTitle . "'";

$result = $db->query($sql);

if($result !== false) 
{
    $cols = $result->columnCount();           // Number of returned columns

    echo 'Number of returned columns: '. $cols. '<br />';

    foreach($result as $row) 
        {
          echo $row['TOT_EMP'] . ' - ' . $row['H_MEAN'] . ' - '. $row['JOBS_1000'] . ' - ' . $row['A_MEAN'] . ' - '. $row['H_PCT10'] . ' - ' . $row['H_MEDIAN'] . ' - '. $row['H_PCT90'] . $row['A_PCT10'] . ' - ' . $row['A_MEDIAN'] . ' - ' . $row['A_PCT90'] . '<br />';
        }
}
```

No matter what variation of the print/echo function, I can't get the data to appear! It's only one row!! Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here's the code from page 3:

```
<?php
$state = $_POST['state'];

$city = $_POST['city'];

try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TeacherData;port=8889","root","root");
}       catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not connect to database.";
    exit;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT OCC_TITLE FROM teacherdataall WHERE PRIM_STATE='" . $state . "' AND AREA_NAME='" . $city . "';");


echo "<br>";
echo "<form action='fourth_page.php' method='post'>";
echo "State: ";
echo "<select name='state'><option value=$state>$state</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "City: ";
echo "<select name='city'><option value=$city>$city</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<select name='jobTitle'><option value=''>-- Job Title --</option>";

if ($stmt->execute()) {
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['OCC_TITLE'] . '">' . $row['OCC_TITLE'] . '</option>';
        echo "<hr>";
    }
echo "</select>";
echo "<button type='submit'>Next</button>";
}
    echo "</form>"; 



?>
```

Completion edit: I was getting a bad value passed from $_POST due to not adding single quotes around the html value=$city. Everything is fixed now! Thanks @Ray!

Comment: Your query is dependant on what's coming from your form. How does it all work?

Comment: Does your `if` statement succeed?

Comment: @halfer If statement does succeed partially, I get the column count which is correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The form is working properly, the first 3 pages function beautifully. The problem is the 4th page (this one) doesn't have the same <select> needs as the first three. Edit: Also, this one is pulling 10 columns, whereas the first three are pulling one column.

Comment: I think Ray's answer below may be what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately Ray's answer didn't work as written...

Comment: **Why not `LIMIT 1` if you need ONE ROW!?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colCount()` tells you number of columns requested not the results your getting back.  You probalby want `rowCount()` as you allready know how many columns you've explicitly set in your query. In your case your select statement has: TOT_EMP, H_MEAN, JOBS_1000, A_MEAN, H_PCT10,H_MEDIAN, H_PCT90, A_PCT10, A_MEDIAN, A_PCT90.  This means you're always going to get back then number 10 for number columns you specify in your SQL query.

All that being said, I suspect your query is running successfully, but returning an empty set of results (no matches).  Try running the query  you build in `$sql` manually.

You also need to fetch the rows from the result if you want to treat it as an associative array:

```
 $rowCount = $result->rowCount(); 

 echo 'Number of returned results: '. $rowCount. '<br />'; 

 $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  foreach($rows as $row) 
  {
       //... rest here
```

My final note is you should not be using $_POST array data directly in your query unless you really want SQL injection.  Use  prepared statement and bind, bind, bind your way to happiness:

```
$sql = "SELECT TOT_EMP, H_MEAN, JOBS_1000,A_MEAN,H_PCT10, H_MEDIAN,H_PCT90, A_PCT10,
        A_MEDIAN, A_PCT90 FROM teacherdataall  WHERE PRIM_STATE=:state AND    
       AREA_NAME=:area  AND OCC_TITLE=:jobTitle";


 $area = "$city, $state";
 $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
 $statement->bindValue(":state", $state);
 $statement->bindValue(":area", $area);
 $statement->bindValue(":jobTitle", $jobTitle);

 $result = $statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was currently looking for this and it was quite difficult to do the most liked option above. I found someone who posted a similar question and it worked for me to get a dropdown list of the sql.

I hope this helps anyone looking for a slightly different answer.

[This is the code i used and on the first try my problem was fixed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33560055/12091735)