# Dropdown option query sql return repeated

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

How do i stop the query for my dropdown from repeating as in the picture below?

[image: Dropdown image]

Please select CD Price:

```
<select name="CDPrice">
    <option value="">
        <?php
        include 'database_conn.php';
        if (!( is_object($conn) && ( get_class($conn) == 'mysqli' ))) {
            die("DB connection failure.");
        }
        $rsCDprice = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nmc_cd.CDPrice FROM nmc_cd");
        if (!$rsCDprice) {
            die("No result from DB query."); //probably invalid SQL, table error, etc.
        }
        if ($rsCDprice->num_rows < 1) {
            die("No rows returned from DB query."); //query runs OK, but nothing is found in DB to match.
        }
        while ($Catpriceresult = mysqli_fetch_array($rsCDprice)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $Catpriceresult[0] . "'>" . $Catpriceresult[0] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute below code.
Please select CD Price:

```
<select name="CDPrice">
    <option value="">
        <?php
        include 'database_conn.php';
        if (!( is_object($conn) && ( get_class($conn) == 'mysqli' ))) {
            die("DB connection failure.");
        }
        $rsCDprice = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT nmc_cd.CDPrice FROM nmc_cd");
        if (!$rsCDprice) {
            die("No result from DB query."); //probably invalid SQL, table error, etc.
        }
        if ($rsCDprice->num_rows < 1) {
            die("No rows returned from DB query."); //query runs OK, but nothing is found in DB to match.
        }
        while ($Catpriceresult = mysqli_fetch_array($rsCDprice)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $Catpriceresult[0] . "'>" . $Catpriceresult[0] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `DISTINCT` or `group by` for this.

1. `group by`

   ```
   SELECT nmc_cd.CDPrice FROM nmc_cd GROUP BY nmc_cd.CDPrice
   ```
2. `DISTINCT`

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT nmc_cd.CDPrice FROM nmc_cd
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Select [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) values from the DB (unique values)

```
SELECT DISTINCT nmc_cd.CDPrice FROM nmc_cd
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nmc_cd.CDPrice FROM nmc_cd
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

In a `table`, a `column` may contain many `duplicate values`; and sometimes you only want to list the `different (distinct) values`.

The **DISTINCT** keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

syntax:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
    FROM table_name;
```